# UIImageView not centered in cell

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I'm having issues centering my UIImageView in a UITableViewCell.

[image]

The image below you can see it's not correctly aligned. My cell is setup like so, with the image view pinned to the top, bottom and sides of the cell, centered horizontally and aspect ratio on.

[image]

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong here?

UPDATE: Curiously if I tap on the cell and select it the image then centers correctly.

Comment: Did you make sure the tableview itself has the correct constraints to the layout ?

Comment: You also have to center contentMode of UIImageView. this can be done in IB

Comment: @RJE tried this and the result is no different

Comment: @SwiftRabbit yup. leading and trailing space to super view is 0.

Comment: Are you sure your image doesn't have a transparent bar on the left side :) I think your cell is longer than your table width. So problem is not with the image, it correctly centered in the cell. But cell is bigger. Check if a part of the cell is cut-off due to bigger size.

Comment: @RJE just checked the table with and the cell width. Both are 320.

Comment: @RJE just noticed that if I tap on the cell and selected it, the image then centers correctly ...

Comment: That means cell didn't get layout correctly. You can call layoutIfNeeded() on cell after setting the image. But normally you shouldn't have to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
//Or
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit;
```

Hope it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove leading and trailing constraints and add Center Horizontally constraint from your imageView to the label which is above that imageView.

Answer (score 0):

Please add following 2 constraints and image will starts appearing in centre of parent view.

1) Centre horizontally in parent
2) Centre vertically in parent

[image]

Comment: have this. and the result it no different

Comment: @Kex Please show me all constraints you have applied on cell.